# Prove that a set is not bounded

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that the set:

$$M= \{x-\frac{1}{x} : x > 0 \}$$

is not bounded

I have had similar problems but when the set are bounded, i found infM and supM by first finding a potential max or min and for the case of upper bound:
Prove that there is no smaller upperbound then the one i found.

Now, how does one go ahead and prove that a set is not bounded? 
Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $N>0$ is not $N+1-\dfrac{1}{N+1}>N?$

For any $\dfrac{1}{N}>0$ is not $\dfrac{1}{N+1}-(N+1)<-N?$

So, the set cannot have any positive $N$ as an upper bound nor $-N$ as a lower bound.

Comment: Don't we ignore when x is say 1/2? 
How does this really prove that the set M does not have an upper bound?
Sorry if I'm slow

Comment: @einar $\dfrac 12+1-\dfrac{1}{\dfrac12+1}=\dfrac56>\dfrac12.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that if $x\geq n+1$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $0<1/x\leq 1$ and
$$x-\frac{1}{x}\geq n+1-1\geq n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( x - \frac1x \right)= \infty$

Hence $$\forall W > 0, \exists N > 0, x > N \implies x - \frac1x  > W$$

Hence it is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Find two unbounded sequences in the set, one diverging to $+\infty$, the other to $-\infty$.

E.g. $n-1/n>n-1$ for all positive integers $n$, so $(n-1/n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ diverges to $+\infty$. You can find a similar one for $-\infty$ by considering $n^{-1}-1/(n^{-1})$ for integer $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:(0,\infty )\rightarrow M, f(x)=x-\frac{1}{x}$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0-\frac{1}{0+}=0-\infty=-\infty$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x)=\infty -\frac{1}{\infty }=\infty -0=\infty$.

Thus $M=(-\infty,\infty)$, i.e. $M$ is not bounded.